# Modal Bottom Sheet in Jetpack Compose for Activity

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I have bottom navigation bar. So my composable functions do not take up the full screen size.

When I use `ModalBottomSheetLayout`, it opens in the composable fun, not in the activity, like when i was using it before when using `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

I don't want to write my `ModalBottomSheetLayout` on the upper level, I think that this is not the right approach.

And i don't want to use the old `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, since compose is everywhere in a project.